# Using HTTP input for AWS MediaConvert

Tags: aws-media-convert

I'd like to use HTTP input for MediaConvert.
Source file is placed on Azure Blob Storage and exposed via SAS URL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/http-input-requirements.html says URL cannot include parameters.
However I can process such URL (like `https://storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/this_is_dummy.mp4?sp=r&st=2024-03-12T02:24:56Z&se=2024-03-12T10:24:56Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxx`) as input.

Is this expected behavior?
Can MediaConvert acutally accept URL with query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are accurate. URL Parameters are not currently 'officially' supported. Some parameters 'may' work for some jobs, but again URL parameters are not officially supported at this time.

One workflow option is to have an AWS Lambda function use all the necessary parameters to retrieve the source URL via curl or wget, and write the file to a secure AWS S3 bucket. Then the same Lambda can trigger a MediaConvert job for the file. One benefit of this workflow is that the Lambda could choose different job templates based on the desired outputs.

This workflow would be subject to the Lambda function's maximum runtime of 15 minutes. File transfers taking Longer than 15min would need to be performed via EC2 or CloudShell.  Another lambda could then delete the copied file once the conversion job is complete.

You can see more about Lambda default limits at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html